# barman PostgreSQL: FAILED

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, barman

I am in the process of setting up a database backup system using Barman.

My database is a postgreSQL db.

When I run

> barman check main-db

I get the following error:

> ```
>         PostgreSQL: FAILED
>         directories: OK
>         retention policy settings: OK
>         backup maximum age: FAILED (interval provided: 1 day, latest backup age: No available backups)
>         compression settings: OK
>         minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 0 backups, expected at least 0)
>         ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
>         not in recovery: OK
> ```

The code I'm using in my barman.conf:

```html
ssh_command = ssh postgres@10.0.0.XX

conninfo = host=10.0.0.XX user=YYYYYYY dbname=ZZZZZZZZ

retention_policy_mode = auto
retention_policy = RECOVERY WINDOW OF 7 days
wal_retention_policy = main
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The `barman check` output contains two errors, the first one is critical:

- PostgreSQL: FAILED

It means that your barman user cannot connect with PostgreSQL using the credentials you provided in the `conninfo` parameter.

You can try it yourself by becoming the barman user and executing psql passing the content of `conninfo` as the only argument (it requires PostgreSQL clients installed on the server):

```
psql 'host=10.0.0.XX user=YYYYYYY dbname=ZZZZZZZZ'
```

It must connect to the target PostgreSQL servers without asking for any password.

The `backup maximum age` error is normal because you don't have any backup. However, it is not a blocking one, so it will not prevent you from taking your first backup.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.

When attempting to call psql 'host= ...... " I get the following:

"could not connect to server: connection refused Is the server running ........"

On the server running my Postgresql DB I called the following:
"nmap 10.0.0.27 -p 5432" and recieved the following message:

"PORT START SERVICE
5432/tcp closed postgresql"

So im guessing my next focus should be looking at opening the above port?

Comment: UPDATE: 'psql 'host=10.0.0.XX user=YYYYYYY dbname=ZZZZZZZZ' 

Does NOT work, however 
'psql -h 10.0.0.XX -p 3385 -U USER DB' does work.

Comment: So your PostgreSQL server runs on  a non-standard port. You must specify it in the `conninfo` parameter by adding ` port=3385`

Answer (score 0):

This issue has now been resolved.

I solved this issue by ensuring that conninfo= had all the correct information. (Including password= field)

Comment: To store passwords, it is batter to use the `.pgpass` file in the barman user home. Doing that way the password is totally managed by PostgreSQL client library and never appears in the process listing output. Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you deleted your barman user from PostgreSQL or you recreated that PostgreSQL cluster using `postgresql-12-setup initdb` command. Either you recover from old backup or you can do follow below steps.

```
postgres@pg$ createuser -s -P barman

postgres@pg$ psql

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_start_backup(text, boolean, boolean) to barman;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_stop_backup() to barman;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_stop_backup(boolean, boolean) to barman;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_switch_wal() to barman;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_create_restore_point(text) to barman;
GRANT pg_read_all_settings TO barman;
GRANT pg_read_all_stats TO barman;
```

For streaming backup, you need to create streaming connection.

```
postgres@pg$ createuser -P --replication streaming_barman
```

Next update your pg_hba.conf file with your granted ip address.